# JQuery: DOM state not updating after detach and appendTo

Tags: jquery, append, detach

My goal is rather than populating a div group to a long list of elements is to move that div instead every time a click event happens.

```
<div data-target="group1">
   <div id="common-element">Move me</div>
   <div class='list'>List 1</div>
</div>

<div data-target="group2">
   <div class='list'>List 2</div>
</div>    

<div data-target="group3">
   <div class='list'>List 3</div>
</div>

...
...

$(document).on('click', '.list', function(){
   $('#common-element').detach().appendTo($(this).parent());
});
```

Now, everything seems OK as #common-element changes location every time I click any of the .list elements.

After some time I had to do:

```
console.log($('#common-element').parent().data('target'));
```

And the problem starts. .data('target') always returns group1 even after #common-element was already moved to another group. It's apparent that even though the detach() and appendTo() happened, the state of #common-element itself was left behind.

My question is: Is there a way that I can update the state of #common-elements?

Comment: The code shown works: https://jsfiddle.net/7rb8g0gu/ - please [edit] the question to provide enough code to duplicate the problem. As an aside, you don't need `.detach()` because `.appendTo()` on its own will move the element.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I think the problem is when the lists are dynamically-created elements.

Comment: If the group elements are made dynamically then may be you are not changing their ids and may be you are having same id on multiple groups so it gives same id for multiple groups.

Comment: OK, I've solved it. I also updated the codes on my question to reflect my actual implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the data() method couldn't keep up with dynamic changes. Its value keeps getting left behind. So instead of using data(), just use the good old attr('data-x') method.

```
// Not working
console.log($('#common-element').parent().data('target'));

// Working
console.log($('#common-element').parent().attr('data-target'));
```